# RegEx for parsing Facebook graph queries for top level fields only

Tags: javascript, regex, facebook

I am trying to parse a graph request with a shape similar to this:

```
name, feed.limit(20) {
  id, name, source, attachments {
    target, type, title
  }, full_picture, description, caption, from, created_time, status_type, link, shares, likes, actions, updated_time, type, message,
  comments.limit(10) {
    comments, message, comment_count, from, created_time
  }
},
 conversations.since(12321) {
  messages.limit(10) {
    message, created_time, from, id, subject, to, attachments, shares
  }, updated_time
},
picture {
  some_property
}
```

And I would like for the RegEx to catch everything **but** :

`name,feed,conversations,picture`

I tried using this RegEx `\..*(\(.*\)|\{.*\})` which seems to be catching more than I desired.

**EDIT:** I am looking to end up with a string of '`name,feed,conversations,picture`'

Comment: I didn't quite understood which part you want to exclude. Could you please post expected output for clarity ?

Comment: I edited it, if that helps?

Comment: `name, feed` are top level fields. How is `picture` top level field ? If you consider `picture` as top level then `conversation` is also a top level field.

Comment: You are correct. That was a mistake on my part. I want conversations too